# How do I use date formatting in Python to show 4 digits for a small year?

Tags: python-3.x, date, format

If I understand the date formatting from the [Standard Library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) correctly, the following

```py
from datetime import date
date(1, 2, 3).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

should produce `"0001-02-03"`, but instead it produces `"1-02-03"`.

I tried this in versions 3.7-3.10 with the same outcome. Am I missing something?

Can I get the year to always have 4 digits using just the datetime format codes? I understand that I can individually format each of the date's fields, such as `<date>.year`, as 0-padded integers and form the string that way.

Comment: I'm running version 3.10.2 and it gives the correct output.

Which module do you load? I'm running "from datetime import date". >>> date(1, 2, 3).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
outputs
'0001-02-03'

Comment: The latest version of Python I tried this on is 3.10.0 from conda on wsl2 / Win10 x64, I used `from datetime import date`

Comment: However, the description of the `%Y` format didn't change in the docs since at least 3.5.9

Comment: Also, I just tried `f"{date(1, 2, 3)}"`, and this one produces `"0001-02-03"`, so maybe that's the answer to my main question. But I do get the impression that the standard library is broken

Comment: I am also getting `1-02-03 ` using python 3.10.1

Comment: Can't speak as to what version fixed this, but I'm now getting the right output with 3.10.7.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) of `datetime` library, you need to manually zero pad years less than 4 digit width.

```
The strptime() method can parse years in the full [1, 9999] range,
but years < 1000 must be zero-filled to 4-digit width.
```

You can try this:

```py
dt = date(1,2,3)
print(f'{dt.year:04}-{dt.month:02}-{dt.day:02}')

# output: 0001-02-03
```

Comment: My question was about `strftime()` (formatting), not `strptime()` (parsing)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is reported since 2011 and it seems that no native solution (ie part of standard Python distribution) as been found as Python relies on C stdlib library which behavior is platform dependant.

Some comments at https://bugs.python.org/issue13305 recommendeds to use tempora

Exemple with year 200 using Python 3.10.11 on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04

- "%Y"

  - Windows : "0200"
  - Ubuntu : "200"
- "%4Y"

  - Windows : raise `ValueError: Invalid format string` exception
  - Ubuntu : "0200"